# OCR app in android studio (greek characters)

Tags: android-studio, ocr, google-vision, google-mlkit

I am trying to develop a simple OCR app in android studio, that works offline only. I want the camera to detect a text that has only **greek** characters and print it on the screen (in **greek** characters).

I tried to use Google vision API and MLkit for text recognition but in both of them the labels of the image are returned in English only.

Can anyone recommend another API or is there any way to use the two apis that i referred to in another way?

Thank you

Comment: According to Google, Cloud Vision should include Greek https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages

Comment: ML Kit currently only supports Latin script, but that will be extended with Japanese, Korean, Chinese and Devanagari script in our upcoming release. Support for Greek is still on the backlog, we don't have a committed timeline yet.

Comment: @Chrisito Thank you for the info